# Is ajax call coming from my site, and Zend F

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, security, zend-framework

I have a url (controller/action) which I access with ajax.

Being ajax, anyone could copy the javascript to their own site and access the same url without going through my site at all. (correct me if I'm wrong)

So my question, how do I know for certain that the call originated from my site and not from an external source.

To clarify, I use Zend Framework and have activated context switch json for this action. So answers specific to Zend are welcome in case Zend has special handling for this.

Answer (score 0):

if ZF doesn't have special handling ( witch i don't think so ) , you can send a hash to the javascript when the js is outputed to the browser , send the hash back with the ajax call and test it , the hased value should be random for each request (and stored in the session for later testing).

Comment: How do you suggest I send a hash to the javascript when the js is outputed to the browser? The only thing I can think of is when the js loads, it should request a hash, but again I think anyone could request this hash the same way. Can you suggest a better way to implement this?

Comment: in you're layout at the head you can "<script type='text/javascript'>var ajaxHash = <?php echo $this->ajax_hash;?>;</script>" , this way the variable ajaxHash can be accesed from all you're js . you can go eaven further and make a view helper that builds the hash , saves it in the session and output's it to the browser , it's realy a pice of cacke

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] to see which address the request is coming from 
[Check this post as well](http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/674717-reg-expression-get-referers-domain) 
you can also use $this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest(); to see if the request is an ahax request.
Hope it is helpful to you.